# Doctrine -Matching entities on common attribute (OneToMany & ManyToMany)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mapping, dql

I am trying to match two entities based on a set of criteria but I can't seem to make it work in this particular case.

For the purpose of the example, let's say I have:

Article with N tags
Category with 1 tag

What I would like to do would be to, in my repository do something like:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('article')
  ->join('App\Enttiy\Category', 'c', Join::WITH, 'c.id = :category_id)
  ->where('c.tag IN article.tags')
  ->andWhere(':category_id', $category->getId())
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

Of course, in this example, the simplest way would be to define a relationship between my objects but in my real case, this relationship would be a nightmare .

The problem I face is the `where` line as the `IN` clause doesn't work that way.

Anyone has an idea of how I could use DQL to do this ? :)

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `andWhere` will not work, you need to use `->setParameter()` instead, like this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('article')
  ->join('App\Enttiy\Category', 'c', Join::WITH, 'c.id = :category_id')
  ->where('c.tag IN article.tags')
  ->setParameter('category_id', $category->getId())
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

After, you forgot an `'` in your `join`, here: `'c.id = :category_id`, I added it in my example (don't know if it's a typing error).

Please try with this and tell me if you have an error again and if you have an error, please tell me what is it.